# How to fix userWarning in Dash plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I was recreating a data visualization project with dash plotly in python, when I run the app. I have got this problems

> UserWarning:
> The dash_html_components package is deprecated. Please replace
> `import dash_html_components as html` with `from dash import html`
> import dash_html_components as html

I have import all my essential packages as follow:

```
from dash import dbc, Input, Output
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import date
```

So  how should I get rid off this **userWarning error**?

Comment: You probably still have an `import dash_html_components as html` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the dash_html_components package is deprecated. This means that it is no longer supported by Dash and will eventually be removed.

To fix the error, you need to import the html component from the dash package instead.

```
from dash import html

# Other imports...

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Hello, world!"),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```